# Matlab: Combining columns of cell array to single cell array while keeping the ' '

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array that looks like this

```
names =

  1×8 cell array

  Columns 1 through 3

    {'CRCGN014_HEPG2_…'}    {'CRCGN013_HEPG2_…'}    {'PCLB003_HT29_24…'}

  Columns 4 through 6

    {'PCLB003_HA1E_24…'}    {'PCLB003_HA1E_24…'}    {'PCLB003_HCC515_…'}

  Columns 7 through 8

    {'PCLB003_HT29_24…'}    {'PCLB003_HCC515_…'}
```

and I want to combine them for it to look like:

```
{ 'CRCGN014_HEPG2_…' , 'CRCGN013_HEPG2_…' .... }
```

I've tried to use:

```
cat(2, names{:}) 
strjoin(names,"', '") 
names[{:}]
```

but to no avail. Can someone let me know if it's even possible to format it that way?

I saw many posts on how to combine the strings but I want to keep the strings intact and with a "," between each string in the cell array

Comment: Aren't the two instances you show actually the same? A 1×8 cell array of char vectors. It may be just a matter of displaying: `{ 'CRCGN014_HEPG2_…' , 'CRCGN013_HEPG2_…'}` is displayed by Matlab as shown in your first snippet

Comment: Oh? I did not know that. I spent way too much time trying to change the formatting when it was actually the same thing... Thanks for this!!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason to why you would like this format in particular? If knowing the purpose, it might also be easier to adapt the solution accordingly.

Currently, your array *names* is a character array, meaning that it's functionality is different from Matlab's string arrays. More information on the difference and similarities between the two may be found in the [documentation on *Characters and Strings*](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html#:%7E:text=A%20character%20array%20is%20a,working%20with%20text%20as%20data.).

Presuming it does not affect your following code, I believe converting your array to a string array might be the solution you are looking for. See the following example:

```
char_arr = [{'A'}, {'B'}, {'C'}]
string_arr = string(char_arr)
```

producing the output:

```
char_arr =

  1×3 cell array

    {'A'}    {'B'}    {'C'}


string_arr = 

  1×3 string array

    "A"    "B"    "C"
```

**Edit** Rereading your question, I believe I might have misunderstood. Are you looking for one string which combines all entries in *names*, but keeping the ' and a comma between?

If so, then perhaps this solution might work:

```
char_arr = [{'A'}, {'B'}, {'C'}]
string_arr = string(char_arr)

string_arr = strcat("'", string_arr, "'")
string_arr = join(string_arr, ',')
```

producing

```
char_arr =

  1×3 cell array

    {'A'}    {'B'}    {'C'}


string_arr = 

  1×3 string array

    "A"    "B"    "C"


string_arr = 

  1×3 string array

    "'A'"    "'B'"    "'C'"


string_arr = 

    "'A','B','C'"
```

Comment: I tried out your code with a extra line to make it a cell `cellstr(string_arr)` and it produced `{''CRCGN014_HEPG2_3H_X3_B29_E17','CRCGN013_HEPG2_24H_X2_B29_P01'....}`. There's 2 ' so it doesn't work. The comment by @Luis above is the correct answer